# store the retrieved data and send it to provided mailid

Tags: android, email, messagebox, information-retrieval

As per the client purpose, I have to make an app of retrieving message data in background and send to his email.
Actually I can't get any idea how to store the retrieved  data and how to send it on provided email.
I have made a main class having email field and an another class of retrieving message data and a service class .
please suggest how can I do it.....

Comment: Use AsyncTask to retrieve the data in background and use Intent.ACTION_SEND to send the mail

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will fire when any sms received and sends email to the particular mail id:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmsApp.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

}
```

BroadCastReceiver:

```
 public class SmsApp extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > -1) {
                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
                            context.startActivity(intent2);
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                /*intent2.putExtra("sender",
                        messages[0].getOriginatingAddress());*/
                intent2.putExtra("message", messages[0].getMessageBody());
                context.startActivity(intent2);
            }

        }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

SecondActivty:

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String sender = bundle.getString("sender");
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    intent2.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "recipient@example.com" });
    intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            message);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2,
                "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out
                .println("There are no email clients installed.");
    }
}
}
```

Add Permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: this will work in background only once you run that in any mobile if you get any sms it will send email in background its broadcast receiver

Comment: just change this email id : recipient@example.com to your receiver email id

Comment: no once you try this code by using two emulators send sms from one emulator to other before that install this app in receiving emulator....

Comment: but I need to keep recipient@example.com dynamic.

Comment: ya you can do that also instead sending email in broadcast receiver you can write this code some where else from where you want to give data dynamically but you have to send this message body to that activity as bundle simple

Comment: please provide your email id.

Comment: sir this code retrieves only the last inbox sms. Rather I want to retrieve the updated sms comes after sending the last one

Comment: i m not getting you ...you want send email after receiving sms or sending a sms be clear

Comment: Acc. to me............If in my mobile I have 8 msg ,first retrieve  that 8 msg and mail on Id.Suppose I set 5 hrs to resend next mail and in between I receive 5 more msg then that updated 5 more msg will send after 5 hours of 1st mail

Comment: in the SmsApp class you have :  intent2.putExtra("message", messages[0].getMessageBody()); in this messages[0] means last msg messages is an array which contains all received msgs....now it depends on you how you want use that you can retreive all msgs also...

Comment: Actually My app stops unexpectedly while launching on avd

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the data you want to send to a file on the SD card.  Here is the how you format the intent for what you want to do (from code I am using to email an XML file I have already written to the SD card):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailID)      // The string that has the email ID you are sending to
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI);    // The URI of the file on the SD card
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email:"));
```

I just learned this myself.  You must put the file to attach to the email on the SD card in a public place for security reasons.

Comment: ......but sir I have nothing to do with UI.All the process should be in the background i.e retrieve data and mail it.I am confused that how I store the retrieve data and mail on provided id

Comment: maybe you can use EXTRA_TEXT instead of the EXTRA_STREAM and just send the text you want without having to save it first.